# How to redirect to specific action in area admin by asp.net core mvc?

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a login page and I want to redirect each user to the specific action of admin area. I've found a lot of links about how to redirect to the particular action. For example, I've tried these methods `RedirectToPage`, `RedirectToAction`, `RedirectToRoute` but all of these methods didn't work for me.

You can see what is my issue when I've used this method.

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard",new { area = "Admin"});
```

[image]

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null){
   ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
   if (!ModelState.IsValid){
      return View(model);
   } else {
     var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName,model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
     var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
     if (result.Succeeded){
        if (user != null){
           ApplicationUser appUser = new ApplicationUser(){
              Id = user.Id,
              Name = user.Name,
              UserName = user.UserName,
              Email = user.Email,
             LastName = user.LastName,
           };
           var userRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(appUser);
           if (userRole != null){
              if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)){
                 if (_userManager.IsInRoleAsync(appUser, "مدیر کل").Result){
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard",new { area = "Admin"});
                    // return RedirectToPage("/Dashboard", new { area = "Admin" });
                    //return RedirectToPage("/Admin/Views/Dashboard/Index.cshtml");
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
   return View(model);
   }
}
```

---

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areas",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});

app.UseMvc(routes =>{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

---

```
[Area("Admin")]
[Authorize(Roles = "مدیر")]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you decorated the class of `Dashboard` with a `[Area("Admin")]` ?

Comment: @itminus,Yes I did it.What is the issue?

Comment: it seems that you're generating the url incorrectly, it usually happens when you don't have such a route (e.g. don't have such an area) . Could you plz post the code of the Dashboard controller ?

Comment: @itminus, I've added.